# Does asio::ip::tcp::resolver::async_resolve need to be external canceled?

Tags: c++, c++11, network-programming, boost-asio

I use the function `async_resolve()`

```
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;

namespace asio = boost::asio;


template <class Request, class Response>
class HttpsClient : public std::enable_shared_from_this<HttpsClient<Request, Response>>
{
  mutable asio::io_context::strand  m_strand;
  tcp::resolver                     m_resolver;
  const std::string                 m_host;
  const std::string                 m_service;

  void doSend(Request request, Handler handler)
  {
    ...

    m_resolver.async_resolve(
      m_host, m_service,
      asio::bind_executor(
        m_strand, std::bind(&HttpsClient::onResolve, this->shared_from_this(), _1, _2)
      )
    );

    ... 
  }
  
  void onResolve(const boost::system::error_code& ec, tcp::resolver::results_type results);
```

Should I cancel `async_resolve()` for example after some timeout?
My question is - does `async_resolve()` give any guaranties to return in smart time limitations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd have more high-level timeout that will cancel any DNS request *as well as other IO operations* when they fail to complete in timely fashion.

After all, it's only marginally interesting to know the difference, and a DNS resolution is usually a step in a sequential IO chain that represents something like "lookup, connect, handshake, receive, reply".

Of course, make sure to log the actual cause of the timeout. This can be as simple as:

```
 void on_timeout(error_code ec) {
     if (ec != asio::errors::operations_aborted)) {
          _resolver.cancel();
          _socket.cancel();
          // any other parts of the highlevel IO operation that might need cancelling
     }
 }
```

The `operations_aborted` is what indicates cancellation. So, we checked it to avoid cancelling other operations when the timer *itself* is cancelled (e.g. what happens naturally during the destructor or when setting a new expiration).

Now you can detect `operations_aborted` in your completion handler(s) for individual steps and use that to log appropriately ("on_resolve: operation aborted") so you have the information. If you wish you can add a more verbose message whenever the `on_timeout` was hit so you can see the difference between other logic flows that result in aborted operations.

> My question is - does async_resolve() give any guaranties to return in smart time limitations

I'm not actually sure about that. And the above is why.

It seems very reasonable to assume that all DNS clients inevitably have a timeout, because the protocol is UDP, which means inherently susceptible to packet loss. It would simply be irresponsible to not expect and handle packet loss (in fact, there will no doubt be a "retry N times" approach for the same reasons).

I do notice some other applications that tend to get stuck for some fixed amount of time when DNS is not responding, but I'm not sure what makes it timeout. I suppose it might be platform dependent.